# Source Controlled Files from Azure DevOps not showing up in VS for Mac

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio for Mac along with Azure DevOps (Git) for source control. I can confirm that I am working on the correct branch and that I have correctly cloned the branch.  I have a folder called Project in my solution which from DevOps has the following contents:

[image]

However, when I expand the folder in the solution from Visual Studio for Mac, I only see the following:

[image]

If I reveal the Project folder contents in finder, I do in fact see all files

[image]

My project compiles fine and I can navigate to those views from the application, they just don't show up in the solution.  Is there something I can do short of removing the files from DevOps and manually re-adding them to the solution?

Thanks.

--- Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by right-clicking on the folder and select Add -> Existing files and selecting the files that were not being listed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to close Visual Studio for mac and then delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin`, `obj` folder. After doing this, restart visual studio for mac and reopen your project to test again.

[image][image]

Comment: @hugh-lin-msft, unfortunately that DID NOT work.  Anything else you can think of?

Comment: Can you give a sample of csproj ?

Comment: Hi Hugh,  I finally managed to get the files in there by right-clicking on the folder and selecting Add Existing Files. I double-checked to make sure tracking was still enabled from Git and it is.